# How to do a full refresh (submit form) per CSJS in XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

I need to submit a form with full refresh per CSJS in an event. 
I know the solution to click the submit button. But is there a way to do it directly with JavaScript on client?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "a full refresh per event" mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten
Thanks for your attempt!

Comment: You're welcome. Obviously Oliver Busse understood you completely :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround is to place a button with SSJS in a hidden div and then triggering it via CSJS. The button may do whatever you want, e.g. submit the form (save the datasource).

The cleaner approach would be to set the $$xspsubmitid with CSJS and then submitting the form. A possible way is described here: http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC